# Display divs in 2 columns ordered from above to below

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to display divs in 2 columns ordered from above to below:

I tried the following solution based on column-count which works nice if the number of divs is even but breaks if it's odd.

```css
.container {
  column-count:2;
}
.square {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="square">1</div>
<div class="square">2</div>
<div class="square">3</div>
</div>
```

Then I tried a solution based on flex, but I can't seem to find a solution for the order:

```css
    .container {
      display:flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .square {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid black;
      flex: 0 0 50%;
      height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="square">1</div>
    <div class="square">2</div>
    <div class="square">3</div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is smoothing like this:

[image: target]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `display:inline-block;width:100%;` to the square element:

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square">1</div>
  <div class="square">2</div>
  <div class="square">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but your solution won't work if you have padding in the square

Comment: @Melchia add `box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: Never mind it works if I add   box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: why doesn't it work when we have only 2 divs please ?